# Guidance on Seeding Data Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm having problems with seeding some constant data when `dropcreatedatabase` is initiated.  I have looked over some similar questions but I'm having difficulties understanding why my code isn't working.

All help is greatly appreciated (c:

Here is my SampleData Model with Seed Data

```
public class SampleData : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<fotmEntities>
{
    protected override void Seed(fotmEntities context)
    {
        var genres = new List<Genre>
        {
            new Genre { Name = "Specials" },
            new Genre { Name = "Online" },
            new Genre { Name = "Services" },
            new Genre { Name = "Food" },
            new Genre { Name = "Misc" },
            new Genre { Name = "Auto" }
        };var localities = new List<Locality>

        {
            new Locality { Name = "Location1" },
            new Locality { Name = "Location2" },
            new Locality { Name = "Location3" },
            new Locality { Name = "Location4" },

        };

        new List<Discount>
        {
            new Discount { Title = "Title A", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Specials"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location1"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
            new Discount { Title = "Title B", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Specials"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location2"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
            new Discount { Title = "Title C", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Services"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location3"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
            new Discount { Title = "Title D", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Food"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location4"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
            new Discount { Title = "Title E", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Misc"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location1"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
            new Discount { Title = "Title F", Genre = genres.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Name == "Auto"), Information = "8.99M", Locality = localities.Single(a => a.Name == "Location2"), DiscountArtUrl = "/Content/img/placeholder.gif" },
        }.ForEach(a => context.Discounts.Add(a));
```

Here is my context model:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

public class fotmEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Locality> Localities { get; set; }
}
```

and my Global.asx

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(
            new fotm.Models.SampleData());
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What isn't working exactly? No data in DB? Data not as expected? Do you get an exception?

Comment: When I debug there is no seed Data persisting through.  Do you need to look at my controller and view as well?  No Exceptions, No Errors,  Just no Data being displayed

Comment: Did you look into the DB directly (with SQL Server Management Studio for example or another tool) if there are data in the tables or not?

Comment: I can see that I have an active connection with Visual Studio in Server Explorer.  Having trouble connecting to it with SQL Server Management Studio.  Troubleshooting now and will respond with an answer soon.

Comment: I've seen seeding with the initializer fail sometimes and what happens is the db gets created but it's not seeded. This is usually because you're missing some data in the initializer. For instance you might be passing a null to a datetime datatype or something like that.

Comment: Fixed.  I was having problems with LocalDb and created a fresh instance of Compact4.0.  I wish I could give more insight on why this worked.  Thanks to all for the comments.